# Associating filetypes without using absolute paths

Tags: filetype

I figured this would be easy both with **[ahk](/questions/tagged/ahk)** and **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** but I'm having some trouble.

What I'm trying to do is quite simple, I want to make a file to pre-configure the settings for my favourite video player. I already did most of the legwork, but setting file associations is tripping me up.

The portable installer doesn't add file associations and if I try in video player settings it will refer to the base app rather than the portable launcher.

So now I'm trying to make a simple tool to configure filetype associations without using absolute paths, because like I said this program is portable, and if the program moves the paths would break. If I avoid using absolute paths then I can put the tool, lets call it "`Configure Filetype Associations.exe`" in the same folder as "`PotPlayerPortable.exe`" and configure it that way.

Here is what I tried so far in **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)**, if I can't figure that out I'll try again with **[ahk](/questions/tagged/ahk)** but all the examples I saw used absolute paths which like I said is a problem:

```bash
assoc .mkv=PotPlayerPortable.MKV 
ftype PotPlayerPortable.MKV="PotPlayerPortable.exe" "%1"
```

I was hoping my batch file would detect the full path automatically based on location but it's not working.

**EDIT 1**: So I actually made quite a bit of progress today. I decided if I can't use relative paths then I would use **[ahk](/questions/tagged/ahk)** to capture and store the working directory in a variable and create an absolute path using that variable.

The problem is, there is a third party to worry about, besides `ASSOC` and `FTYPE` I mean, there is a key called `Progid` found here:

```bash
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ext\UserChoice
```

And in **[windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7)** it overrides `ASSOC` and `FTYPE`.   Worse, the key is protected. Now I'm forced to ask, how can I override protection on a registry key LOL sounds malicious. I know I can go into permissions but I'm trying to automate everything here, it shouldn't be this hard to make a simple program to configure file extensions for a given program, and I want backwards compatibility to **[windows-7](/questions/tagged/windows-7)**, **[windows-vista](/questions/tagged/windows-vista)** can suck my fat tits...

**EDIT 2**: `REGINI` command looks promising, investigating now...

**EDIT 3**: Looks like this will probably work, the computername parameter is out of the question since it would break portability, but regini -h should work if I can figure out the syntax. Watching a Nick Cage movie, I'll test in a bit. Should be something like:

```bash
regini -h hivefile hiveroot HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ext\UserChoice [1 5 7 20 21]
```

Once permissions are edited I can edit or delete the key, that's a total of 4 steps just to register 1 extension :/

**EDIT 4**: So editing permissions to modify the key was harder than I could possibly have imagined. I can use SetACL to apply permissions, but not to delete deny entries, and ofc deny entries override. Fortunately I was only prevented from modifying the key though, I do have delete access so a simple script that deletes and recreates the key should do the trick even without SetACL. I probably won't try this until morning but I think I finally have a solution.

**EDIT 5**: I mostly figured it out, but I still can't proceed without deleting the Deny entry.

This is what I have so far:

```bash
assoc .mpg=PotPlayerPortable.mpg
ftype PotPlayerPortable.mpg="PotPlayerPortable.exe" "%1"

reg delete HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mpg\UserChoice /f
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.mpg\UserChoice /v Progid /t REG_SZ /d Applications\PotPlayerPortable.exe /f

pause
```

I suspect the problem is `REG.exe` is not getting elevated even though **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** is.

Comment: so my gut reaction, is that the system won't allow associations to relative paths, because that opens up several vulnerabilities, and may allow attackers to trick your system into running a malicious exe by inserting it into the path or whatever.

Comment: I don't really get why. Windows file registrations are in registry keys. The whole idea of portable apps is that they do _not_ change the registry keys - that's what makes them portable in the first place. However, someone seems to have created a tool for exactly this: https://github.com/SiL3NC3/PortableRegistrator/

Comment: The point of all this is since it's portable I can move my settings to a new computer very easily, I never have to re-install and re-configure my settings, but I do have to associate the filetypes every time. It would be wonderful to have a fast way to do this. PortableRegistrator does look promising, I'll check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured it out, and I didn't actually need any absolute paths at all! Follow these instructions to create your own mini app to register extensions for 1 or more programs. Here is an example code, I will explain below:

FLV.bat

```
Pushd "%~dp0"
assoc .flv=PotPlayerPortable.FLV
ftype PotPlayerPortable.FLV="PotPlayerPortable.exe" "%1"
regedit /s FLV.reg
reg add HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.flv\UserChoice /v Progid /t REG_SZ /d Applications\PotPlayerPortable.exe /f
```

NOTE: I know what your thinking but regedit works better than reg this time because of the deny permission entry in Win7.

FLV.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.flv\UserChoice]
```

This batch file must be run as administrator. Create a new file for every extension your changing, for clarification this script is currently rigged to register the extension .FLV to run using a program called PotPlayerPortable.exe which must be located in the current directory.

Now there are 2 ways we can proceed, one way will change all the extensions, the other will change the extensions only if a certain .ini file specifies a certain option as 1, for example we might use FLV=1. I will explain this method since it's more useful. Create a master batch file beginning with a start /w command, this will allow us to run an AutoHotkey script, which we will convert to exe using Ahk2Exe, which can be found in the AutoHotkey v2.0.2 installation folder. The /w argument means our master batch file will wait until our AutoHotkey program closes before proceeding to the next command, and unlike AutoHotkey's RunWait command it doesn't need to see a window to do this properly. This AHK script will read our .ini file and based on settings detected there we will use an if/else command to either assign the extension, or not. Any setting other than "1" will fail. That's pretty much it, and to keep all our files packed into a single program we can use Bat to Exe Creator on out master batch file, give it a good icon, add vista administrator access, choose invisible application, set temporary files to delete on exit and in the Include section we will add our files, leaving us with a single program that will run quickly and clean up afterwards. Keep the .ini file outside the .exe if you want this to be customizable. Simple, right? I wanted the code to be easy to understand. I suggest you hang onto AutoHotkey and Bat to Exe Creator, they are both amazingly useful programs. I love a program that does exactly what is needed and nothing more, that's why I'm actually using a much older version of Bat to Exe Creator. Here is some example code:

Master Batch File.exe

```
timeout 5
start "" /w AHKScript.exe
```

AHKScript.exe

```
A_FLV := IniRead("Associations.ini", "Settings", "FLV")
if A_FLV = 1{
Run("FLV.vbs")
sleep "50"
}
```

Associations.ini

```
[Settings]
FLV=1
```

Downloads:

AutoHotkey:
https://www.autohotkey.com/

Bat to Exe Creator:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/5muq1k44nipshgy/Bat_to_Exe_Converter.exe